# Set of Social Values of different Samples: ANOVA?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, manova

I have been collecting data for 10 consecutive years. One survey each year, different subjects (samples between 105 and 120), Likert scale 1-5 for each of 30 social values. What is the most appropriate method to look at the changes that have taken place year after year regarding these values? In other words, how can I explore whether the importance of each one of the social values have changed or not? (ANOVA? Pearson? Does it make sense to use both methods?)

Comment: Question needs clarification: One survey each year? Different randomly chosen subjects each year? How many subjects? (Just your grandmother and Uncle Fred each year?) What kind of data? (Likert scale responses? Yes/No for each of 30? _Pick_ 5 most important out of 30? _Rank_ top 5 out of 30? Etc.?)

Comment: Thank you for the response. One survey each year, different subjects (samples between 105 and 120), Likert scale 1-5 for each of 30.